# Scan for water in 2D procedural terrain locale

Tags: 2d, algorithm, procedural-generation, terrain, water

In my 2D-sideview game, I have certain biomes, each one having a unique sea level, or water height, (depending on the humidity of the biome). The terrain is composed of stacks of blocks, each being a type of land or being water. I want the height map to look something like this:

[image: what I want]

*Terrain height does not always correlate to water height. It does so here for demo purposes.*

Each lake must have a constant water height across.

**What I've tried:** To calculate if there is water in a region, I want to know the minimum water height of all biomes in that region. That will be the lake's water height.

However, I don't know how far the region extends on each side, so I can't find the minimum water height. If the water height was global/constant, I would search in both directions until I found a block above sea level (or a maximum distance was reached), but I don't know the water height, because I can't search for it, because I need the other water heights to search for this water height!

**Some ideas that seem inefficient:**

- Search for the endpoints of a potential lake at each biome water level, and choose the smallest water level to generate the lake.
- Find the smallest biome level in a max distance on each side, and choose the smallest water level to generate the lake.

Please tell there is a better way!

**Edit:**

- Terrain stacks (columns) are generated individually, then loaded into memory. When the player reaches a certain distance from the stack, it will get unloaded, and then regenerated again when the player is near. *Every time a terrain stack is generated it must be exactly the same.*
- For querying stack heights over and over again for calculating whether water should be on a stack, I cache the height and biome of some stacks beyond the loaded stacks in each direction; thus, it is not considered loaded (so entities can't move), but the basic information does not have to be recalculated.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how your regions are loaded/generated/distributed?

Answer (score 5):

This is a [**maximum subarray problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) in disguise! It's a popular interview question. Instead of finding subarray sums, we're finding terrain that can hold water, and instead of finding *the* biggest subarray, we're finding all subarrays.

With the maximum subarray problem, we can track the current maximum subarray as we scan the array. The key insight is that once the sum is less than zero (because we have negative values), there is no point keeping the current subarray, so we reset and start counting from the current position instead.

Here's how we'd do it. Suppose we have the current terrain (a simplified version of your example:

```
#
##   ##
### ####
##########   #
########### ##
##############
```

First, flip it so that we start from the lower end (here we'll just scan right-to-left instead). Then transform it into the maximum subarray problem by looking at the **slope** of the terrain:

```
Heights: [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Slopes:   [-1,-1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,-1,-1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Then, we scan the slopes looking for largest subarrays. Since we're looking for valleys that can hold water, we are actually looking for *negative* sums.

```js
const levels = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const slopes = [-1,-1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,-1,-1, 1, 1, 1];
let currentSum = 0;
let currentWaterStart = 0;
let minSum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < slopes.length; i++) {
  currentSum += slopes[i];
  minSum = Math.min(currentSum, minSum);
  if (currentSum >= 0) {
    if (minSum < 0) {
      console.log('Found water from ' + currentWaterStart + ' to ' + i);
      console.log(' depth ' + -minSum + ' level ' + levels[i+1]);
    }
    currentSum = 0;
    currentWaterStart = i;
    minSum = 0;
  }
}
```

The time complexity is O(n) and space complexity is O(1).

Comment: Nice use of the JavaScript snippet tool!

Comment: This is really great, but how would it work with an infinite amount of terrain? In other words, you provided a finite set of terrain stacks to be processed in the algorithm; but in my game, I don't know where the end of my search is - that's the problem I'm facing.

Comment: The end of the search can be as big as your terrain, because it's always possible that you have a single gigantic ocean. Having said that, this algorithm is incremental, so you can add a piece of terrain, and perform a search on that new terrain up to the current peak of your terrain. It sounds like you would want some limits on how big the water features can be.

Comment: Okay, but how do you know which one's the lower end if it goes on indefinity? I'm really confused.

Comment: Also, sorry but how would I modify this if I _know_ the water height given the minimum water height due to the biomes in the water region? In other words, the water height is known (depending on the biomes of the land making up the water region).

Comment: Square peg into a round hole. This by no means addresses all of the OPs concerns. Their issue is primarily one of _ordering terrain generation passes in the scope of potentially infinite terrain._ Hence their ongoing questions directly above this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than giving you exact solutions, I'm rather going to primarily offer you ideas and tools that may help you to solve problems of this sort. *Teach a man to fish* and all that.

**Principles**

1. Any computation must be limited (in range).
2. When you have problems like "I cannot do that till I do this, but I cannot do this till I do that", you are usually doing too much at once. You need to layer your approach more finely to do one set of things at a time, then another set, then another etc.
3. You are better off reducing the dataset you work with, even in finite ranges.

I'll refer back to these principles by number through this answer, so keep them in mind.

**Finity vs. Infinity**

> how do you know which one's the lower end if it goes on indefinit(el)y?
>
> I don't know how far the region extends on each side

...Your words. You need to start defining limits (principle #1), because *your code* cannot process inifinite ranges in finite time. Only you can decide those limits. What's the worst that can happen? You a try a value and it doesn't work out: so try another. Until you get something that works.

**Biomes**

I noticed in your question that you have a blue and a green area, one smaller than the other. OK. These are usually called terrain *chunks*, but we'll call them *biomes*: these are important processing elements, as using them *we don't have to* scan every single column every time we need to do something - e.g. seeking water. Instead, we can scan just the biomes.

You can generate your world in two ways: by column primarily, OR by biome and *then* by column. I would suggest the latter, as it gives better control and efficiency (principle #3). Imagine we start out generating the world as a biome array:

```
[
  {
     type:sand
     start:0
     end:7
     columns: [empty]
  },
  {
     type:grass
     start:7
     end:13
     columns: [empty]
  },
  {
     type:stone
     start:13
     end:17
     columns: [empty]
  },
  ...
]
```

Now you have an abstract idea of each biome: What it consists of, where it `start`s in x, where it `end`s in x. You can see that the `end` of each biome is neighboured by the `start` of the next.

Now we take this data and from it and (principle #2) create an array of heights, per biome as `width = biome.end - biome.start; biome.columns = new Column[width]`. Then we populate each column in that array. So for the array above we might get

```
      *#
*    **##
**  ***###
*******#####   oo
*******######oooo ...etc.
```

*Looping over the columns* as shown here, we'd now fill in some important intermediate data to the biomes array:

```
[
  {
     type:sand
     start:0
     end:7
     columns: [7 elements]
     minheight: 2
     maxheight: 5
  },
  {
     type:grass
     start:7
     end:13
     columns: [6 elements]
     minheight: 1
     maxheight: 5
  },
  {
     type:stone
     start:13
     end:17
     columns: [4 elements]
     minheight: 1
     maxheight: 2
  },
  ...
]
```

We've now populated `minHeight` and `maxHeight` fields accordingly for that biome from our generated columns. This gives more control, as you will see next.

Remember: Chunks are used to *limit the problem* (#2). That's why we generate biomes *first* (i.e. our primary data structures) and *then* only generate columns. This makes the world manageable.

You can cheaply generate large numbers of biomes without the considerably higher cost of generating large numbers of columns for every one - *until later*. What's more: You could dictate the `minheight` and `maxheight` *before* you generate the columns. Maybe you can already begin to see how this might help you to determine lake heights without *having to examine every single column*: You could maybe even (no guarantees), before ever generating columns, pre-dictate min and max levels of lakes, given the min and max ground heights. Then generate ground and water columns.

**Scanning solutions**

You cannot determine water levels for columns / biomes you haven't generated yet. You cannot scan around the current location when you haven't yet generated the locations that come after it. With that in mind, here are some solutions.

1. Only scan backward, to biomes you have already generated along with their water heights (assuming you always generate forward from `world.biomes[0]`). This will always be a scan of some fixed distance backward, let's call it `scanDistance`.
2. Generate forward, but only scan from a biome that is say `scanDistance / 2` units back from the highest-indexed biome (last generated). Generate at least `scanDistance` biomes before you begin scanning. Now you can scan back, and forward to the end, by `scanDistance / 2`, from the centre, without hitting the bounds of your world's array of biomes.

OR (my recommendation)

3. Generate biomes only in your 1st pass (see *Chunks / Biomes*); figure out in your 2nd pass what the water levels will be. To do this, run through the world around the current location-of-interest by some excessive extent first, in a `scanDiameter` that is centred around the current location, generating land with indentations first. P.S. You can generate ***many*** biomes this way (probably millions if you like, though I'd start smaller - see principle #3). Then run a second pass and evaluate parameters like `minheight`s and `maxheight`s of those areas.

Remember, you cannot scan further than the range of biomes (even if they don't yet have columns) that you have already generated (principle #1). Your code must take this into account.

**Decisions, decisions...**

Maybe you are happy with just generating `minheight` and `maxheight`, then generating columns, then determining lake levels via scan. Maybe you prefer to pre-generate numbers for `minheight`, `maxheight`, `minlakeheight`, `maxlakeheight` before touching concrete columns at all. Maybe you generate land columns and in another pass, use that to determine water columns / levels. Or maybe you do something altogether different that is only inspired by what we've talked about here.

Procedural generation is a field of infinite possibilities.  Nothing we've talked about is set in stone. Don't be locked into just one way of thinking. Keep an open mind in your explorations.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response, but these ideas conflict with my generating processes, for my overarching principle: _Every time a terrain stack is generated it must be exactly the same._ I have a feeling this would depend on the direction from which you are generating. Also, I use simplex noise to generate biomes and the heightmap (which is hard to control like you suggest in your answer).

Comment: @clabe45 Let me know if you would like to continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=gamedev.stackexchange.com). Because as far as I can tell, the other answer has not addressed your concerns, and it will not. If you want a solution, work _with_ me.

Comment: I would like to know more, I'll take you up on your offer for the chat.

Comment: @clabe45 OK. You can join [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73581/clabe45-procedural-water-scan).